# Do Noachides have minhagim?

Tags: minhag, gentiles, noachide-laws

According to Judaism, do Gentiles have minhagim as it relates to how they live out the Seven Laws of Noah, or are they capable of having or establishing them?

If Gentiles can/do have minhagim, are individual Noachides obligated to follow a specific minhag based on their ancestry and/or local community to the extent that one exists, or is this purely voluntary?

Comment: None of the Noahide Laws really cater to the ability of having many minhagim to pass on. What kind of minhagim can you think of that could be passed on?

Comment: I don't remember the source but I recall something about non-Jews being prohibited from making their own holidays and customs around the sheva mitzvos.